# Resizable svg rect element using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

Hi I am new at Svg and I am trying to learn ReactJs day by day. I have a question and I do not have any idea whether it is possible. I have **Svg** element and I wrapped element of its with **g**. g element has one **rect** element and I want to make it resizeable with mouse event such as this resizable event [here](https://svgjs.com/svg.resize.js/) if it's possible.I did it resizable with value using form input but i did not achive that with using mouse event. I did not find a correct answer or solution on web? Could you help me at this issue ?

Here is structure :

```
 <svg>
     <g>
        <rect>
           //something
       </rect>
     </g>
 </svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need learn basics of SVG and its geometry.
If I were you, I would start here https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/
SVG - is not simple.
In your case solution depends on what you want to get as a result. You can wrap whole `<svg>` with some `div`, and set div's width and height, but width & height of `svg`, `rect` set 100%. Or you can set width & height only for `svg`, but after it you need set `viewBox`. What is it? Read articles that I left above.

Comment: I understand but I have to use svg because of snapshot event. I mean my project have continued for a long time. I can not change structure from svg to div at right now. I am looking for a method to solve my problem.

Comment: Anton says you should **learn** SVG first, before you can **use** SVG. Hold on with React for a week, learn SVG first, try to accomplish what you want with native SVG and native JavaScript. React is only sugar to help you built Single-Page-Applications faster

Answer (score 0):

You can make SVGs as a component

```
import React from 'react';

const Svg = (props) => (
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="" {...props}>

    <path d="" />     

    //something  

  </svg>
);
export default Svg;
```

Usage:

```
<Svg fill="red" className={classes.icon} ...props />) 


<Svg fill="#00000"  height='35px'  width='35px' ...props />)
```